# Tikz Coordinate Matrix Transformation with non-square units

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw

I'm attempting to use the coordinate transformation matrix, but it seems to not align properly with non-transformed objects when the `x` and `y` units are not set equivalently.

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cc}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=2cm,y=2cm]
        \fill[cyan, cm={1, .2, 0, .8, (0, 0)}] (4, 4) rectangle (6, 6);
        \draw (4, 4) rectangle (6, 6);
    \end{tikzpicture} &
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1.6cm,y=2cm]
        \fill[cyan, cm={1, .2, 0, .8, (0, 0)}] (4, 4) rectangle (6, 6);
        \draw (4, 4) rectangle (6, 6);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Misaligned Transform]

The image on the left is the one with square coordinates, the one on the right is the one with non-square coordinates. On the left, the transformed rectangle meets the bottom left and top right of its bounding box.

I would have expected that the differences in unit size would not have affected the transformation as to cause the transformed and non-transformed shapes to misalign as they do on the right.

Is there any way to rectify this, apart from drawing it square and utilizing a `resizebox`?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer @Rmano

Comment: I'd say it's a bug. I've opened a new ticket: https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/1007

Comment: @HenriMenke Thanks. I've added a few additional findings I had to the bug you created.

Answer (score 1):

First things first, the `x` and `y` values (or vectors actually) specify a transformation between the [*xyz* coordinate system](https://tikz.dev/tikz-coordinates#pgf.xyz) (the one without units, three-dimensional) and the [canvas coordinate system](https://tikz.dev/tikz-coordinates#pgf.canvas) (with units, always two-dimensional).
The transformation matrix specified by `cm` is applied onto the coordinates of the canvas coordinate system.

Lets apply the first transformation (*xyz* → canvas) before we look more into it:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[cyan, cm={1, .2, 0, .8, (0, 0)}] (8cm, 8cm)  rectangle (12cm, 12cm);
\draw                                  (8cm, 8cm)  rectangle (12cm, 12cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[cyan, cm={1, .2, 0, .8, (0, 0)}] (6.4cm, 8cm) rectangle (9.6cm, 12cm);
\draw                                  (6.4cm, 8cm) rectangle (9.6cm, 12cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

These two diagrams still look the same as yours.

Now, when you use `cm = {a, b, c, d, (x, y)}` you set up a transformation that converts an input coordinate *s* = (*s*₁, *s*₂) (always in the canvas coordinate system) to a TeX coordinate *t* = (*t*₁, *t*₂)
according to
[image]
i.e.
[image]

With

- *a* = 1,
- *b* = 0.2,
- *c* = 0 and
- *d* = 0.8 as well as
- *x* = *y* = 0

that means

### Code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz, amsmath}
\tikzset{
  debug coordinate node/.style={node font=\tiny, xscale=.75},
  dcn/.style={debug coordinate node/.append style={#1}},
  save cm/.code=\pgfgettransformentries\pgfcma\pgfcmb\pgfcmc\pgfcmd\pgfcmx\pgfcmy,
  debug coordinate/.style args={#1/#2:#3}{insert path={
    [save cm] node[centered, inner sep=+1pt, circle, fill]{}
    node[debug coordinate node] {$ \begin{alignedat}{2}
      #3_1 &= \pgfcma\cdot\mathrm{#1} + \pgfcmc\cdot\mathrm{#2} + \mathrm{\pgfcmx}
        && = \pgfmathprint{(\pgfcma*(#1)+\pgfcmc*(#2)+\pgfcmx)/1cm}\mathrm{cm}\\
      #3_2 &= \pgfcmb\cdot\mathrm{#1} + \pgfcmd\cdot\mathrm{#2} + \mathrm{\pgfcmy}
        && = \pgfmathprint{(\pgfcmb*(#1)+\pgfcmd*(#2)+\pgfcmy)/1cm}\mathrm{cm}\\
    \end{alignedat}$}}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[cyan, cm={1, .2, 0, .8, (0, 0)}]
             (8cm,  8cm) [below right, debug coordinate= 8cm/ 8cm:m]
  rectangle (12cm, 12cm) [above left,  debug coordinate=12cm/12cm:m];
\draw        (8cm,  8cm) [above right, debug coordinate= 8cm/ 8cm:n]
  rectangle (12cm, 12cm) [below left,  debug coordinate=12cm/12cm:n];
\end{tikzpicture} &
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[cyan, cm={1, .2, 0, .8, (0, 0)}]
            (6.4cm,  8cm) [below right, debug coordinate=6.4cm/ 8cm:m]
  rectangle (9.6cm, 12cm) [above left,  debug coordinate=9.6cm/12cm:m];
\draw       (6.4cm,  8cm) [above right, debug coordinate=6.4cm/ 8cm:n]
  rectangle (9.6cm, 12cm) [above left, dcn={yshift=.25cm},
                                        debug coordinate=9.6cm/12cm:n];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]